# How does the node.js REPL stringify output?

Tags: node.js, read-eval-print-loop, stringify

How does the node.js REPL stringify the objects that it prints? I became curious after running into this oddity with an array containing a key-value pair **(?!)**:

```
> var arr = [1]
undefined
> arr
[ 1 ]
> arr.key = "value"
'value'
> arr
[ 1, key: 'value' ]
```

The typical functions don't appear to be generating exactly `[ 1, key: 'value' ]`.

```
> arr.toString()
'1'
> JSON.stringify(arr)
'[1]'
> require("util").inspect(arr, {showHidden: true})
'[ 1, [length]: 1, key: \'value\' ]'
```

The last one's almost it, but has an additional `[length]` (to clarify, the quotes obviously don't matter). I'm running node **v0.10.33**.

Comment: it just special case for what `util.ispect` return. `util.inspect` return you string, but REPL show it "as is"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there; [util.inspect](http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options) returns a string and is called without `showHidden`:

```
> require("util").inspect(arr)
'[ 1, key: \'value\' ]'
> console.log( require("util").inspect(arr) )
[ 1, key: 'value' ]
```

If you log a string to the console, it'll be wrapped in quotes, but `console.log` does not do this. Write `inspect`'s output to a file if you want to verify that it's exactly the same as `console.log`'s output:

```
> require("fs").writeFileSync("dump.txt", require("util").inspect(arr));
```

In your console:

```
$ cat dump.txt
[ 1, key: 'value' ]
```

---

Regarding the first paragraph:

> array containing a key-value pair (?!):

It's not that weird - arrays are objects, so it's perfectly valid. But it might be confusing to other people looking at your code. :-)

Doing that is not much different from this:

```
var fn = function() {}
fn.key = "value";
```

It'll look just like your array example if you were to log this.

Comment: also function already has some key-values: `(function foo(){}).name`

Comment: Yep, but you'll only see those if you pass `{showHidden: true}` to `inspect`.

Comment: "hidden" - what's this? keys from prototypes?

Comment: Oh, of course! Should've omitted `showHidden` (I'm aware about the quotes -- it was the `[length]` that threw me off). While it's certainly valid, I haven't encountered it in the wild before and was wrongly under the impression that arrays were strict primitives.